# How to know what post params are being sent to my api

Tags: php, string, api, post

So im using this lib that sends crash reports to my api , but they have poor documentation and im unsure which params to be expecting from them. How would i go about setting up a test function that would grab all the received post params , turn them into a string and store them in my db ( for lack of a better method )

Comment: well check what it returns, on the basis of that only

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to serialize the entire `$_POST` array, either via PHP's `serialize()` method, or [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) if you want to use it with something else.

IE

```
$db_data = json_encode($_POST);
```

Sadly this method will make it very hard to create analytics since you cannot aggregate fields.

If you are interested in those, your best bet would be to create another table with a schema of `(id, key, value)` and store each `$_POST` key individually.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what the params are you can step through the POST array like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    echo "POST Param Name: " . htmlspecialchars($key) . "</br>";
    echo "POST Param Value: " . htmlspecialchars($value) . "</br></br>";
}
```

At this point just use a simple SQL INSERT statement to store them wherever you like.